# OpenBSD 6.1 Python Executable Permission denied

Tags: python, openbsd

I recently update my server from OpenBSD 6.0 to 6.1

Since this update, the python console is no longer available (I have version 2.7 and 3.6 installed, both have the same behavior)

when I try to launch a python console (either in version 2.7.13 or 3.6.0) it say 'Permission Denied':

```
$ python2.7
/usr/local/bin/python2.7: Permission denied.
```

I already checked the file permissions in /usr/local/bin but there is nothing wrong at is set as 'rwxr-xr-x root bin'

I tried to uninstall the python packages then reinstall them but it has not solved the problem.

Is there something I need to check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `wxallowed` as mount option to `/etc/fstab`. You can see the real error in the dmesg.

Comment: yeah!!! I flag my `/usr` partition with `wxallowed` then the python console works again!!! but no errors appear in the dmesg... I also found this page: [link](http://daemonforums.org/showthread.php?p=59012) Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you remove `wxallowed` from fstab, reboot and run again python, you will see the errors in the dmesg. Something like `python2.7(12345): mprotect W^X violation`.